# efficient sorted Cartesian product of 2 sorted array of integers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, cartesian-product, sorting

Need **Hints** to design an efficient algorithm that takes the following input and spits out the following output.

Input: two sorted arrays of integers A and B, each of length n

Output: One sorted array that consists of Cartesian product of arrays A and B.

```
For Example: 

Input:
A is 1, 3, 5
B is 4, 8, 10
here n is 3.

Output:
4, 8, 10, 12, 20, 24, 30, 40, 50
```

Here are my attempts at solving this problem.

1) Given that output is n^2, Efficient algorithm can't do any better than O(n^2) time complexity.

2) First I tried a simple but inefficient approach. Generate Cartesian product of A and B. It can be done in O(n^2) time complexity. we need to store, so we can do sorting on it. Therefore O(n^2) space complexity too. Now we sort n^2 elements which can't be done better than O(n^2logn) without making any assumptions on the input.

Finally I have O(n^2logn) time and O(n^2) space complexity algorithm.

There must be a better algorithm because I've not made use of **sorted** nature of input arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's a solution that's better than O(*n*² log *n*) it needs to do more than just exploit the fact that A and B are already sorted. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279524/).

---

Srikanth wonders how this can be done in O(*n*) space (not counting the space for the output). This can be done by generating the lists lazily.

Suppose we have A = 6,7,8 and B = 3,4,5. First, multiply every element in A by the first element in B, and store these in a list:

> 6×3 = 18, 7×3 = 21, 8×3 = 24

Find the smallest element of this list (6×3), output it, replace it with that element in A times the next element in B:

> 7×3 = 21, **6×4 = 24**, 8×3 = 24

Find the new smallest element of this list (7×3), output it, and replace:

> 6×4 = 24, 8×3 = 24, **7×4 = 28**

And so on. We only need O(*n*) space for this intermediate list, and finding the smallest element at each stage takes O(log *n*) time if we keep the list in a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. It affirms the fact that this problem can't be solved better than O(n^2logn) time complexity. Its useful skill to be able to tell (possibly prove) the tighter lower bound for a given problem. Its clear that we can easily reduce my problem into the one your link points at but there is something we can do in terms of space. May be I can get away without using space by trading little or no time.

Comment: If you can generate the matrix as you go, rather than storing it, then you use only O(*n*) space (not counting the space for the output).

Comment: Could you please elaborate how it is done. We can easily generate cartesian product with 2 for loops each running on an array but it won't be sorted and doesn't use any space. If the output is not stored in the program then we don't count it otherwise it is considered part of algorithmic space complexity.

Comment: I like this approach for the following reasons: 1) generating lists lazily is good as it reduces space requirements from O(n^2) to O(n). 2) Using Heap to find min. we insert n^2 elements into heap and take every element out by the end of algorithm.Both take O(n^2logn) time.

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply a value of A with all values of B, the result list is still sorted. In your example:

A is 1, 3, 5

B is 4, 8, 10

1*(4,8,10) = 4,8,10

3*(4,8,10) = 12,24,30

Now you can merge the two lists (exactly like in merge sort). You just look at both list heads and put the smaller one in the result list. so here you would select 4, then 8 then 10 etc.
result = 4,8,10,12,24,30

Now you do the same for result list and the next remaining list merging 4,8,10,12,24,30 with 5*(4,8,10) = 20,40,50.

As merging is most efficient if both lists have the same length, you can modify that schema by dividing A in two parts, do the merging recursively for both parts, and merge both results.

Note that you can save some time using a merge approach as is isn't required that A is sorted, just B needs to be sorted.

Comment: This is a sensible approach, but still takes O(n² log n).